# Why I can't add fish to /etc/shells?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, command-line, fish

I'm trying to use fish shell as my default shell on OSX. I have installed fish shell using brew and when I wanted to add it to /etc/shells I got this error:

```
tee: /etc/shells: No such file or directory
```

Here's the command line I used:

```
echo "usr/local/bin/fish" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

source: https://hackercodex.com/guide/install-fish-shell-mac-ubuntu/

Is there something wrong with my path?

Comment: That should be `/usr/local/bin/fish`, not `usr/local/bin/fish`.

Comment: The only way I can see that error being produced is if you don't have the directory `/etc`, which seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @chepner, surely that's not the only possibility. Could be that `/etc/shells` already exists as a broken symlink, for example.

Comment: ...that said, questions about system configuration and customization are a better fit for [unix.se], [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), or [apple.se] rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: @chepner I have checked wether the directory /etc exists or not, and I found it and fount shells file too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the recommendation. I will check them :)

Comment: BTW, you might just use `sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish "$(id -u)"` to avoid the requirement that a shell be listed in `/etc/shells` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Because you installed fish with Brew, the binary for fish is different than linux distros:

You should be doing:

```
echo "/usr/local/homebrew/bin/fish" | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

### NOTE:

With the new update on Homebrew the packages are actually symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/fish`.

An easy way for you to know which path to use is either doing `which fish` 
or doing a `ls -la /usr/local/bin` and see if you  have any fish binary in that folder

Comment: Actually I just had to delete ./config/fish. When I ran again fish it recreated the folder with normal permissions. I don't know why /etc folder was private.

Answer (score 0):

**homebrew** installs links to binaries in `/usr/local/bin`. So if you run:

```
type fish
```

it should tell you `/usr/local/bin/fish`, which means you need to edit `/etc/shells` and add `/usr/local/bin/fish`